# Implementing a search to match the specified author and displaying a book by the specified publisher

Tags: c++, algorithm

Hey guys! So i'm having problems with my assignment. I successfully got it to run multiple last names by the author, but now, I need to find all books by author, which means searching the collection for all books that match the specified author and I also need to find all books by publisher, which displays a list of books by the specified publisher. How would I implement this? Would I use string or vector? Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: are you using database to store this values? use foreign key dude

Answer (score 1):

Create a logical entity ( a `struct`) which groups all the required information. For example, `struct Book { string name; string author;...};`, then create a `vector<Book> books` and populate it. After this you can use `std::find` algorithm with a user defined functor to search for the books with the given author.